# Mobile automation with Appium

Tags: android, mobile, browser, automation, appium

Sorry if question is logically wrong. On computer, with selenium we can automate the browser and can control the session of browser. Started to read, found appium for mobile automation, but appium is testing tool, as I understand we can automate something only by usb connection, or via wifi. I understand, need to start an appium server on pc, which will connect to mobile device and so on, not all things are clear for me. And I intuitively understand, the app, which we write to automate some process on mobile devices, just can't be run on mobile device as native app.
In my case need to create an android app, which on run will automate some process on browser. So is there some way to do that, or maybe "appium app" can really launched on android as a native app. Again sorry if question is vague and wrong. Would be happy for help, that fills the gaps in understanding. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: On a non-rooted device there isn't a way to do this, unless the app you wish to automate provides some special API.  On Android you can't send fake mouse/key presses to another app, for security reasons.

Comment: Ok, will know, thank you. Another question, maybe there is way to put appium test app to some cloud server, and devices cound address to the app?